# How to pass number of runtime parameters to variables in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am using Azure Devops pipeline to automate azure alert creation using ARM deployment tasks. In order to automate the threshold values for the alerts I created runtime parameters inside the pipeline, which need to be replaced by a replace token task and will update the corresponding runtime parameter values to the "parameters.json" file.

Here I am facing challenge like, in order to replace the values of runtime parameters to parameters.json, first I need to convert the parameter values to variable either by defining those variables under variable section or by using a bash task separately to output the variable value. I am looking for solutions for below requirements

- Is there any any method to directly update the runtime parameter values to the "parameters.json"
- Can we add sub values to parameter values? For example, only need to have certain run time parameter values if the alert category is logquery type-metricmeasurement and other set of values required if the type is "count type".

Comment: Why would you not want to control this via values in source control? That provides auditing (via commit history), review and approval (via PR), and accountability. When someone accidentally adds an extra zero or two on an alert trigger value and breaks the alert, how will you know what happened, when it happened, and who was responsible for doing it?

Comment: My aim was to get a solution which should be easier for the user end to create the alert creation by putting the desired values for thresholds and dimensions, so i used runtimeparamater to give them to select the values from Pipeline run GUI itself. So As you suggested the strong point, I have a task in my pipeline to validate the jsonfiles before the deployment and have a stge approval to validate and approve the output of above json file validation before the deployment.

Comment: As you suggested, If I i try to consider this from source control poit, The ARM template formatting should be known by each user who are not basically aware of those. is there any alternate way where the end users can easily pass the values to source control managed input file. I searched multiple options, but didnt help me,

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do it with a `parameters.json` it is a bit inconvenient. Why ? Because you have to parse the json and then update the desired nodes in json using PS/Bash script at runtime.

I will propose another solution to do this. Use `template parameter object` instead of `parameters.json`. Just call the ARM template using PS/Bash

example creating a VM-

```
$a = "abc"
$b = "efg"
$c = "hij"
$d = "klm"
$e = "nop"

$paramList = 
   @{
    "Params1" = @{ customVmName = $a ; userImageStorageAccountName = $b ; adminUsername = $c ; adminPassword = $d ; osDiskVhdUri = $e }
   }
    
foreach ($keys in $paramList.Keys)
{   
    $paramvalues = $paramList.$keys
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "deploymentRG" -TemplateFile "YourARMTemplate.json" -TemplateParameterObject $paramValues   
}
```

Coming to part to of your question :
Overriding the values at runtime in Azure DevOps

Parameterize the script and override the values while you call the PS file.
If you are using PS task in Azure DevOps just override the param values in the argument section-

[image]

If you are a PS/Bash guy you can do the manipulation in the part of script lets say setting `$a="abc"` based on a condition or env and for another env a different value, mean to say the overriding of a param value can be done as a code at runtime (Just another option)